# android: running a background task using AlarmManager

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am writing an app which needs to periodically check the server for new messages and notify the user. I have seen some examples using AlarmManager to hit a BroadcastReciever which seems like the right thing to do, but i cant seem to get it to work.

Can anyone show me a step by step tutorial for this sort of thing (repeating alarm which triggers some kind of background code that fires a Notification)?

TIA

Comment: Show us what you have tried, with details on how exactly it is failing.

Comment: My tutorials are in books (sorry!). Perhaps the `WakefulIntentService` page and demo project will help: http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: Share the code please, I'm dying!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is one complete example: http://android-in-practice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch02/DealDroidWithService/

The pattern this example uses, and one that I've found that seems to work well, is to use a boot receiver to setup the *AlarmManager* (and of course also check to start the polling from your main *Activity* too, for the case when your app is installed and the system is not booted) and have the *AlarmManager* send an *Intent* for another receiver: http://android-in-practice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch02/DealDroidWithService/src/com/manning/aip/dealdroid/DealBootReceiver.java

And then from the *AlarmReceiver* start an *IntentService*: 
http://android-in-practice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch02/DealDroidWithService/src/com/manning/aip/dealdroid/DealAlarmReceiver.java

From your *IntentService* then make your network call to poll for data, or whatever you need to do. *IntentService* automatically puts your work in a background thread, it's very handy:
http://android-in-practice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch02/DealDroidWithService/src/com/manning/aip/dealdroid/DealService.java

Check the docs for these classes too, a lot of into in there.

The caveat with this example is that it does *not* deal with the wake lock gap (the excellent CommonsWare code does that if you need it), but it may give you some more ideas about how to potentially address the "poll using AlarmManager and Service" stuff.

UPDATE: the code is now here: https://github.com/charlieCollins/android-in-practice

Comment: This answer seems pretty close to what i did. Should work for you folks.

Comment: You might want to put a WakeLock on the IntentService to ensure the phone does not go to sleep straight after the onReceive has been executed. Scratch that, just read your caveat note...

Comment: All the code for the book is here now" https://github.com/charlieCollins/android-in-practice