# AlarmManager object after turning off and on the phone

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, broadcasting

In my app, I set an alarm

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
...
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

It works fine unless I turn off and turn on the phone.

To be more specific, let's say at 10:20, I set an alarm to 10:22 and I turn off and turn on the phone at 10:21, alarm won't work.

What might be the problem? Is that a broadcast issue of the pendingIntent there or should I set some flags of the alarmManager object for it to work in such conditions?

Comment: you could check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072451/clarification-of-alarmmanager-behavior-in-android. looks similar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation about the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) says that :

> Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but **will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted**.

It seems that the AlarmClock included by default by Android does work even after a reboot.

On way to keep your alarms working after a reboot, is to start your application on boot completed and set up all the alams again with the AlarmManager.
(In fact you may want to just setup your alarms using a Broadcast, not start your app)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup) is a StackOverflow question dealing about lunching an app on startup.

You wan also check out how the default AlarmClock does this by reading from the source.
You can read and download it from [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock)

Comment: does it include turning off the screen?

Comment: `turning off the screen` means the device is asleep. The alarms will be retained of you turn the screen off and don't completely turn off the phone.

Comment: I see, so what happens if the alarm is set to be repeating, and the device sleeps for a long time? does it mean it will get multiple intents (of the same alarm) at the same time ?