# How to Set up Alarm Same like Alarm App in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I am trying to setup alarm outside of my app with little popup box. I made that popup box by using Activity.I been trying for a long time to setup alarm like Alarm app but i get failed in some situations.

I am successful if i am exiting the app from the launch activity by using back button.

But when i press home button the alarm keep working charm but with last used activity in background.

I am not sure why this happening and i would like to know how i can make this work with out any activity in background when i pressed home button.

Here is my onReceiver Code.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    try {
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");

         Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderPopupMessage.class);
         newIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", message);
         newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         context.startActivity(newIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
         e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

}

If you guys provide the link for actual alarm app code that would be fabulous.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after long time

Just Added this in Android Popup Class Manifest File.

```
 <activity android:name=".AlarmPopup" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
          android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
          android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

The problem get solved.

I hope it will help for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should actually try src of Android alarm app [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock) is the link.

have a look on my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11359301/519718)