# How the actual Alarm app is working?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am looking to know how the actual alarm app popup the dialog box on exact time without any activity in background of it. If you could please see my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393744/how-to-set-up-alarm-same-like-alarm-app-in-android) post for the exact solution i am looking for but answer to this question is much appreciated.

**Code for popup**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstance)
{
    super.onCreate(savedinstance); 
    //alarmsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wewillrock);
    alarmsound = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            if(db.getAlarmCount()!=0)
            {
                Cursor alarmcursor = db.getAlarmdetails(this);
                if(alarmcursor!=null)
                {
                    alarmcursor.moveToFirst();
                    String alarmTonepath = alarmcursor.getString(alarmcursor.getColumnIndex(GinoClockDatabase.AL_RINGTONEPATH)); 
                    alarmsound.setDataSource(alarmTonepath);    
                    alarmsound.prepare();
                }
                db.close(); 
            }
            db.close();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block0
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        alarmsound.start();

    ((Activity)Global.context).finish();
    setContentView(R.layout.reminderpopupmessage);  
    settingViews(); 
}
private void settingViews() {
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReminderyes);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReminderno); 
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnReminderyes:
        alarmsound.stop();
        Intent splashscreen = new Intent(ReminderPopupMessage.this,SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(splashscreen);
        ReminderPopupMessage.this.finish();
        break;
    case R.id.btnReminderno:
        alarmsound.stop();
        ReminderPopupMessage.this.finish();
        break;
    } 
}
```

I am looking more than a month for this solution but couldn't find the solution. I think i have asked more than 5 question about this alarm functionality.
I hope i will get answer now.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Create your own popup, and then show it!

Comment: And in your xml file, set the Activitiy to be a dialog theme, in order to get the popup layout like this: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

Comment: thanks for your comment carnal.. actually my alarm is working perfectly fine with the popup. the problem is when popup get displayed i am getting last used activity as a background.. if use see my post you will come to know what was the problem.. please see it my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I see your problem. In order to get rid of the background activity when displaying the popup, use this in your AndroidManifest.xml for the activity popping up as the alarm:

```
<activity android:name=".AlarmPopup" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
              android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks carnal.. It working like charm.. Many thanks for that because i am looking for this more than a month..+1 for that.. and it annoying that just from only one activity when i press home button it goes to the homescreen-->Alarm popups--> After that whenever i open the app it launches that activity.. i am really confusing.. Do u have any idea..

Comment: I don't really understand you. After the popup comes up? You pressed the home button and then when you start the application again it goes to that popup? You should implement then a close button on the alarm with the finish() method in order to remove it from the stack. Don't really understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

here is the link of Android alarm app [git_alarm_app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock)