# How to turn GPS ON in background in android?

Tags: android

I am getting the GPS value in background. For that Am using `Service` for background process. If GPS is disabled means, I used the below code.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
```

It is working when the app is running in the foreground, but it is not working in the background.
I also use the `AlarmManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service won't run for long time.You have to use [AlaramManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

For Long run process.

See the below post

[android: running a background task using AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859489/android-running-a-background-task-using-alarmmanager)

Comment: Thanks!! Yes am using service with Alarm manager and Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: I have followed the same way...But it is not wake-up at particular time in backgorund. Without calling "myIntent" code it is working well both background and foreground.